Connecting cloud run on GCP A to cloud sql on GCBP B using a proxy
So I have been trying this for some times and I can't figure it out. There are multiple ways as per the chatgpt instructions and not a consistent recommendation thus time for human brain here :)
So I am working with client who has cloud SQL instance and cloud sql Auth installed on their GCP (called it GCP B). In my GCP (GCP A), I have a cloud run application that needs to connect to the database (I assume through cloud auth).
I got the client to add my cloud run default cloud run GCP A service account XYZ@compute.googlepais.com to his IAM roles with cloud sql client role. I did the same in my IAM and gave it admin and client role.
and I deployed my cloud run as follows:
gcloud run deploy <SERVICE_NAME> 
--image <IMAGE_URL> 
--add-cloudsql-instances <PROJECT_ID>::<INSTANCE_ID> 
--region  
--project <RUN_PROJECT_ID>
I keep getting connection error.
Then I tried getting the cloud SQL service name from the client and I added it to my IAM and same issue.
What am I missing here? what are the true steps to make it work
I
